# Javascript calling difference

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

What is the difference between the following statements?

```
<tr onclick="javascript:class1.function1()">
<td>HideAlert</td>
</tr>
```

and

```
<tr onclick="class1.function1()">
<td>HideAlert</td>
</tr>
```

I created a webpage with the second method for calling the function and tested in Internet Explorer 6.0 which came with Windows 2003 Server. The function is not called. When i gave "javascript:class1.function1()" in the browsers addressbar, then the function worked. Is there any difference in calling the function with the above mentioned ways?

The script is like below:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var class1 = function(obj) {
this.val1 = obj.val1;
}
class1.function1 = function() {
$('#alertDiv').fadeOut('slow', function() {
});
</script>
```

The jquery version is 1.4.2

Comment: Hmm, `onClick` vs `onclick`? :)

Comment: Both of them have something in common: Bad coding style. You should use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/unobtrusive-javascript/). to add events.

Comment: Does `<tr onClick="class1.function1()">` work in IE6? Note the capitalization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the address bar (or in an `href` attribute, or anywhere else a regular URL might go), `javascript:` is the protocol that identifies a piece of JavaScript to be run in the current page.

In an `onclick` attribute (or any other script context), `javascript:` is a label which may be used like this:

```
javascript:
for( var i=0; i<100; i++) {
    while(true) {
        continue javascript;
    }
}
// bad example, but it works and doesn't cause an infinite loop!
```

In other words, `onclick="javascript:..."` is unnecessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer dude. Can you help me with why the script didn't run on onclick and runs when i pass in address bar?

Answer (score 0):

The first version has a completely redundant [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Their behaviour should be identical.